# How to access to SharePoint Objects (List, ListItem, User, ect) using React and PnP-JS Core with SharePoint FrameWork (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-framework, pnp-js-core, react

I would like to create a WebPart using react and PnP-JS Core with sharepoint framework capable to access SharePoint Objects (such Lists, ListItems, Users, Groups, ect ) in the site where it is deployed and I also want it to be able to perform CRUD Operations on sharepoint lists.

Do you have any simple examples I can look at and test on SharePoint 2016 to help me to get familiarized with this new concept ?

Thanks,

Arioule

Answer (score 3):

You Will find in the following link all available operations of PnP-JS-Core and how to use them with SharePoint Framework.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Developer-Guide